How to add a few missing std:: functions from libstc++6?
I'm compiling a c++ application on a very old system with libstdc++6. This libstdc++6 has functions up to GLIBCXX_3.4.21.
I need to use an external .so library which uses just a few more functions up to @GLIBCXX_3.4.22 and I can't recompile it.
For some other reasons, the old system is too old to be upgraded. The compilation errors are:
undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())'
undefined reference to `std::thread::_State::~_State()'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::thread::_State'
undefined reference to `std::thread::_State::~_State()@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::thread::_State@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'
undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())@GLIBCXX_3.4.22'

I found a newer libstdc++.so.6 and I managed to make work my app with:
LD_PRELOAD="libstdc++.so.6"

but I would like to avoid mixing different libstdc++.so.6 and overwriting the original library.
How could I find and add the relevant C++ code to my app in order to provide the missing functions of the std namespace? I think that I'm missing only the following functions:
std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())
std::thread::_State::~_State()
std::thread::_State


It's not a matter of adding missing functions; you need to figure out why the library is broken. The missing names are all library internals; the code you've compiled tries to use them because the headers you used say that they're there. The fact that they're missing means that the headers and the library don't match.

Perhaps I'm not clear enough. The library is not broken, it has been compiled with a new libstdc++. My app is compiled against an older version. That's the point. the header and the library don't match. Perhaps I'm not explaining well the problem.

If the header doesn't match the library, then even if you patch up the missing functions, there's no guarantee that the functions that do exist are compatible with the header. Indeed, libstdc++ explicitly denies it: It is not possible to take program binaries linked with the latest version of a library binary in a release series (with additional symbols added), substitute in the initial release of the library binary, and remain link compatible. The table later on says "GCC 3.4.0: libstdc++.so.6.0.0 (Incompatible with previous)".

When you ship an application to an old distro you also need to ship libstdc++.so , you cannot rely on the system one.
